# Parallel transport of a vector

Tags: differential-geometry

There is a parameterized curve $\gamma(\tau)$ on a $4$-dim manifold. The auto parallel vector $X^{\alpha}(\tau)$ to the curve is needed to find. By definition of auto parallel vectors, the covariant derivative of a vector along the curve must be zero.

In a textbook, it is given as follow:

$$\frac{\partial X^{\alpha}}{\partial\tau}+\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta\sigma}X^{\beta}\frac{d\gamma^{\sigma}}{d\tau}=0$$

I am confused about why the term $\frac{d\gamma^{\sigma}}{d\tau}$ is added? There is nothing similar to that in the definition of covariant derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the ($\sigma$ component of the) velocity vector of the curve. Note that the first term $\dfrac{\partial X^\alpha}{\partial\tau}$ is really wrong; this should be $\dfrac d{d\tau}$, differentiating $X^\alpha(\gamma(\tau))$.

Comment: Thank you! But still have confusion. How $\dfrac d{dt}$ is added? The first part of differentiation is not expressing the change of $X^{\alpha}$ as $\tau$ along the curve grows? It is a covariant derivative along the tangential to the curve direction $\frac{d}{d\tau}$. I was thinking about how to replace $\vec{B}$ to $\frac{d}{d\tau}$ in the definition of covariant derivative $\nabla_{\vec{B}}A$. Following the rule of covariant differentiation how can be understood the attachment of the velocity vector?

Comment: Sorry, $t$ was a typo from habit. The covariant derivative along $\gamma$ is the covariant derivative in the direction of the velocity vector.